# How do I prepend every item in a list of strings in C# with a Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I found a VB version of this here, but I'd like to use a Lambda Expression to take a List of strings and then prepend a string onto every item in the list.

It seems like using the ForEach ends up sending in the string by value, so any changes disappear. Here's the line of code I was hoping to have work.

```
listOfStrings.ForEach((listItem) => {listItem = listItem.Insert(0,"a");});
```

Comment: You can't change a collection while iterating using a ForEach.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you won't be able to use a `foreach` like this.

Comment: Use for, there is no way other than custom extension to use lambda function.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Strings are immutable, they cannot be altered "in place". Therefore, you'd have to replace each entry in the list which you cannot do with `List<T>.ForEach`. At this point you'd be best just making a new list:

```
listOfStrings = listOfStrings.Select(value => "a" + value).ToList();
```

Comment: DOH! You beat me to it. Damn robot test :)

Comment: That was a nice piece of code, +1. Could you elaborate some more on how this works?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to modify the list *in place*, then an explicit `for` loop is appropriate.

```
for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
{
     list[index] = // modify away!
}
```

Otherwise, use the `Select(Func<T, TOut> selector)` with the optional `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` as demonstrated by sixlettervariables.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<string> x = new List<string>();
            x.Add("d");

            List<string> res = x.Select(c => "a" + c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own extension:

```
public static void ForEachChange<T>(this List<T> List, Func<T, T> Func)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
        List[i] = Func(List[i]);
}

listOfStrings.ForEachChange((listItem) => {return listItem.Insert(0,"a");});
```

will work now

Edit:
Now working

Comment: -1, bad strategy if this worked. Regardless, properties (such as List<T>'s indexer) cannot be made a `ref`, nor can `ref` be a part of a generic type specification. C# is not quite C++.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: its fixed now, not sure why you think this is a bad idea

Comment: It's mixing side effects into "functional" style programming. But that's a personal preference, so I'll remove my -1 since this is now working.

Comment: Lambdas, delegates and LINQ are a huge stack of side effects already

Comment: Not in the *functional* sense of the term "side effect". `list.Select(x => x + 1)` does not change `list`.